# Get text String in Between two Strings (keywords) - in Dart - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using this function bellow to capture text **after** a certain keyword in a String of `text` :

```
      static String? _getTextAfterKeyword({
    required String inputtext,
    required String keyword,
  }) {
    final indexKeyword = text.indexOf(keyword);
    final indexAfter = indexKeyword + keyword.length;

    if (indexKeyword == -1) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return text.substring(indexAfter).trim();
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to capture a String of text **in between two keywords** - but what I've tried hasn't worked -

To illustrate this is what I need :

```
inputtext = "Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum FIRSTKEYWORD - text I would like to return - SECONDKEYWORD Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"
```

the function would look something like this :

```
 static String? _getTextInBetweenTwoKeywords({
    required String inputtext,
    required String firstKeyword,
    required String SecondKeyword,
  }) {

   //Some Code

      return the StringInBetweentheTwoKeywords;
    
  }
``
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input and output??

Comment: Please give more detail on what you want to talk about, so that the viewers may understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this do the trick?

```
String capture(String first, String second, String input) {
  int firstIndex = input.indexOf(first) + first.length;
  int secondIndex = input.indexOf(second);
  return input.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);
}

void main() {
  print(capture('FIRST', 'SECOND', 'AAAAAAA FIRST-what should print-SECOND BBBBBB')); // prints '-what should print-';
}
```

Comment: thank you this works!  I'll try to add some code so it doesn't crash when no matching keywords are found - thank you ⚡️